# tQuery.MinecraftChar is not a constructor con tquery.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

tengo el siguiente código que hace uso del script tquery.js:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="./tquery-all.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
world=tQuery.createWorld().boilerplate().start()
character=new tQuery.MinecraftChar({
  skinUrl:'images/3djesus.png'
})
character.model.addTo(world)
</script>
</body>
```

Pero sin embargo no se genera nada, debe estar pasando algo no?

Mi objetivo es conseguir que se genere un personaje de minecraft, aunque sea en negro, y luego ir añadiéndole la skin con este script...

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes añadir la salida de la consola para poder seguir mejor la pista del error?

Comment: Si es verdad se me olvidó ><'. Pero de todas formas ya encontré la solución. Perdí el archivo que daba el error de todas formas... ><'

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta!!!

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="./scripts/tquery-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/tquery.effectcomposer.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/tquery.minecraftchar.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 200%; right: 0;">
    <select id="skinSelect">
        <option value="skins/drfrank_classic.png">Dr.Frank.</option>
        <option value="skins/mario.png">Mario.</option>
        <option value="skins/luigi.png">Luigi.</option>
        <option value="skins/wario.png">Wario.</option>
        <option value="skins/waluigi.png">Waluigi.</option>
        <option value="skins/fawful.png">Fawful.</option>
        <option value="skins/e-gadd.png">E-Gadd.</option>
        <option value="skins/peach.png">Peach.</option>
        <option value="skins/jesus3d.png">Jesus3D.</option>
        <option value="skins/light.png">Light Yagami.</option>
        <option value="skins/jotaro.png">Jotaro Kujo.</option>
        <option value="skins/lenin.png">Lenin.</option>
        <option value="skins/stalin.png">Stalin.</option>
        <option value="skins/makhno.png">Makhno.</option>
        <option value="skins/notch.png">Notch.</option>
        <option value="skins/chuck.png">Chuck Norris.</option>
        <option value="skins/bruce.png">Bruce Lee.</option>
        <option value="skins/agentsmith.png">Agent Smith.</option>
        <option value="skins/elrichmc.png">El Rich MC.</option>
        <option value="skins/kim.png">Kim Jong Un.</option>
        <option value="skins/trump.png">Trump.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button"id="p1"value="Play.">
</div>
<script>
playing=false
world=tQuery.createWorld().boilerplate().start()
world.tCamera().position.z=1.8
character=new tQuery.MinecraftChar({
  skinUrl:'skins/drfrank_classic.png'
})
skinSelect.onchange=()=>{
    character.loadSkin(skinSelect.value)
}
character.model.addTo(world)
world.loop().hook(function(delta, now){
    if(playing==false){
        character.parts.headGroup.rotation.x    = Math.sin(now*1.5)/3;
        character.parts.headGroup.rotation.y    = Math.sin(now)/3;
        var angle   = 1/2 * now*Math.PI*2;
        // move the arms
        character.parts.armR.rotation.x = 1.4 * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI);
        character.parts.armL.rotation.x = 1.4 * Math.cos(angle);
        // move the legs
        character.parts.legR.rotation.x = 1.4 * Math.cos(angle);
        character.parts.legL.rotation.x = 1.4 * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI);
    }
})
p1.onclick=()=>{
    playing=true
}
</script>
</body>
```